# using <a></a> to scroll a single page website

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a single page website and have a problem with the `<a></a>` tags.

I would like when the user clicks a Div they get taken to a different part of the page. At the moment I have `<a></a>` that do that.

```
    '<a href="#divid">About</a>'
```

css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/#two this is a good example of i am using to scroll thru the page

but every time I place these tags around an image in my div all the div click properties stop working. 
Example:

```
<div id="about-button" class="button">
    <a href="#about"><img src="images/menu-about.png"
                          alt="about" class="button"/></a>
</div>
```

I can tell this is happening due to the `a` tag being on top of the div.

My question is there a way to make the `<a>` tag sit under or work side by side with the div and still work??

or if there is no way to accomplish that. any reading I can do or examples of a better way to navigate to a specific part of the page with out the use of the '' tags

Comment: i have <a></a> tags that do that*

Comment: Rather than the '#'s (since you've tagged this jQuery) you could use [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to scroll to the right place instead.

Comment: @matt23: It would be nice if you provide us more code. Like jQuery code, and even better with some 'fiddle'.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't entirely clear. Could you explain what actually happens and what you want to happen? If you have a click handler for the div, show that too.

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var scr = $('#target').offset().top; // top offset of the target element
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scr}, 1000)
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UdK4h/2/)

Comment: sorry to everyone my English is not very good ill try to restructure my question and ask again

Comment: @matt23 that's okay, do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/UdK4h/1/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/#two this is a good example of i am using to scroll thru the page

Comment: I got rid of the div all together! and applied the onclick event of the div to the <a> tag and set the image as the background of the <a> tag. sorry again if i caused any confusion dint mean to wast anyone's time. thank for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manipulate how the DOM elements work, wouldn't it be much easier to change your jQuery selector? http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

Comment: You mean attach the div's click handers to the anchor?

Comment: @Rup Yes, that would be precisely what I mean.

Comment: I got rid of the div all together! and applied the onclick event of the div to the <a> tag and set the image as the background of the <a> tag. sorry again if i caused any confusion dint mean to wast anyone's time. thank for all the help.